# MySQL: Point in Time query using InnoDB log sequence number?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Is it possible to do a point in time query based on a log sequence number?

For example, I would like to do something similar to Oracle's "as of" query

```
select foo from bar as of scn 123923455;
```

which returns a read-consisten result as of that timestamp or system change number.

My application is verifying that the state of two independent database servers is consistent as of a certain operation or point in time.  The data is being replicated via Golden Gate with a Java adaptor, and I intend to store periodic "checkpoints" saying "The data should be consistent as of Oracle SCN x and Innodb log sequence number y."  I should be able to then run a program to verify this is the case.

Comment: Thanks!  Background added.  Basically I want to make some kind of read-cosistent query as of a particular timestamp or sequence number.

Answer (score 0):

it is no similar mechanism to retrieve record state in the past from inside MySQL using LSN.

based on business idea, You can save timestamped state of important data by trigger or procedure.